# Angular 8 facebook login and save data into local storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, facebook-javascript-sdk, angular8

I'm trying to achieve facebook login in angular 8 as per this plugin instructions. but after this implemention when we reload the page i got signout. I want to stay logged in until i loggedout
i use this social plugin for google and facebook

> npm i angularx-social-login@2.2.1,
> angular 8

```
//app module code
let config = new AuthServiceConfig([
    {
    id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    provider: new GoogleLoginProvider("google-app-id")
    },
    {
    id: FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    provider: new FacebookLoginProvider("facebook-app-id")
    }
]);
export function provideConfig() {
    return config;
}

// signin component code
signInWithFB(): void {
    this.authService.signIn(FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
    if (this.loggedIn) {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    }
  }
```

---

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! I think your question is missing the actual problem you are facing? Could you tell use what you try to achieve and what is blocking you.

Comment: @JuhoRutila **[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login/v/2.2.1)** . I'm trying to achieve facebook login in angular 8 as per this plugin instructions. but after this implemention when we reload the page i got signout. I want to stay logged in until i loggedout

Comment: I haven't used this library but seeing from the docs, you have to subscribe to the `authState` provided in the service inside your ngOnInit. `this.authService.authState.subscribe` and get the user detail, who is logged in.
So when you refresh, this subscription will run again and tell u if user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing from the docs, you have to subscribe to the `authState` provided in the service inside your ngOnInit. `this.authService.authState.subscribe` and get the user detail, who is logged in.
So when you refresh, this subscription will run again and tell u if user is logged in or not.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.authService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
  this.user = user;
  this.loggedIn = (user != null);
});
```

Comment: i already place this in the ngOnInit(); is there is another simple way to do it without any plugin

Comment: This is the simplest way, you don't even need to save user data and state in localstorage because angularx-social-login provides an observable which will notify you when user is logged in and when logged out with this authState. 
Are you not getting user object on refreshing page inside the subcription?

Comment: no i didn't get any user object after refreshing page